# Proving Uniform Continuity of $g$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-continuity

I'm self-learning Real Analysis. I would like to request feedback on the below proof specifically, of the claim that when $g:(a,c)\to\mathbf{R}$ is uniformly continuous over $(a,b]$ and $[b,c)$, it is uniformly continuous over the entire interval $(a,c)$.

> **Exercise 4.4.5**. Assume that $\displaystyle g$ is defined on an open interval $\displaystyle ( a,c)$ and it is known to uniformly continuous on $\displaystyle ( a,b]$ and $\displaystyle [ b,c)$, where $\displaystyle a< b< c$. Prove that $\displaystyle g$ is uniformly continuous on $\displaystyle ( a,c)$.

***Proof.***

Let $\displaystyle ( a_{n})\rightarrow a$ be an arbitrary sequence in $\displaystyle ( a,b]$. Since $\displaystyle ( a_{n})$ is Cauchy, there exists $\displaystyle N\in \mathbf{N}$, such that $\displaystyle | a_{n} -a_{m}| < \delta $ for all $\displaystyle n >m\geq N$.

Pick an arbitrary $\displaystyle \epsilon  >0$. Since, Since, $\displaystyle g$ is uniformly continuous over $\displaystyle ( a,b]$, there exists $\displaystyle \delta  >0$, such that for all $\displaystyle x,y\in ( a,b]$, where $\displaystyle | x-y| < \delta $, we have $\displaystyle | g( x) -g( y)| < \epsilon $.

Thus, $\displaystyle | a_{n} -a_{m}| < \delta $ implies $\displaystyle | g( a_{n}) -g( a_{m})| < \epsilon $ for all $\displaystyle n >m\geq N$. Consequently, $\displaystyle ( g( a_{n}))$ is Cauchy and therefore convergent.

Let $\displaystyle g( a) =\lim g( a_{n})$.

Take another sequence $\displaystyle ( b_{n})\rightarrow a$. Since, $\displaystyle ( b_{n} -a_{n})$ is Cauchy, the distance $\displaystyle | b_{n} -a_{n}| $ can be made as small as we please. From the uniform continuity of $\displaystyle g$, it follows that if $\displaystyle | b_{n} -a_{n}| < \delta $, $\displaystyle | g( b_{n}) -g( a_{n})| < \epsilon $. Consequently, $\displaystyle \lim g( b_{n}) =\lim g( a_{n}) =g( a)$.

Define:

\begin{equation*}
h( x) =\begin{cases}
\lim g( a_{n}) & ,\forall ( a_{n}) \ \text{such that }( a_{n})\rightarrow a,\ \text{if } x=a\\
g( x) & ,a< x< c\\
\lim g( c_{n}) & ,\forall ( c_{n}) \ \text{such that }( c_{n})\rightarrow c,\ \text{if } x=c
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Consequently, $\displaystyle h$ is continuous over a compact set $\displaystyle K=[ a,c]$. Thus, $\displaystyle h$ is uniformly continuous over $\displaystyle K$. So, $\displaystyle h$ is uniformly continuous over any subset of $\displaystyle K$, such as $\displaystyle ( a,c)$.

Comment: Looks overly complicated. Leave out the sequences and go from the epsilon delta definition directly.

Comment: @QuantumSpace, can I divide into three cases (I) $x,y \in (a,b]$ (ii) $x,y \in [b,c)$ which are trivial and (III) $x \in (a,b]$, $y \in [b,c)$?

Comment: Your solution works and is perfectly reasonable. To follow QuantumSpace's suggestion, given $\epsilon$, you want to pick $\delta_1$ s.t. $x, y \in (a, b]$ s.t. $|x - y| < \delta_1$, $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon / 2$ and pick $\delta_2$ similarly for $[b, c)$. Then you break it up into the three cases you specified.

Comment: @MichaelHardy No, this works perfectly well. For in this case, we see that because $x < b < y$, we have $|x - b| < \delta_1$ and thus $|f(x) - f(b)| < \epsilon / 2$. And also, it must be that $|y - b| < \delta_2$ and thus $|f(y) - f(b)| < \epsilon / 2$. So $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |f(x) - f(b)| + |f(b) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. That's why I picked $\epsilon / 2$ and not $\epsilon$.

Comment: @MarkSaving : Sorry --- I was hasty.

Comment: @MichaelHardy No problem. At least a third of the time, when someone comments to point out an error it's because I myself was hasty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some value $\delta_1$ is small enough to assure that $|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $x,y\in(a,b]$ and $|x-y|<\delta_1.$

Some value $\delta_2$ is similarly small enough for the interval $[b,c).$

I was going to say $\text{“let }\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}\text{”}$ and leave it there, but then I realized there's the case where $a<x<b<y<c,$ so $x,y$ are not both within the same one of those two intervals.

So pick $\delta_1,\delta_2$ small enough so that $|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon/2$ whenever $x,y$ differ by less than $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ and both are in the same one of the two intervals. Then consider the case $a<x<b<y<c$ and $|x-y|<\delta.$ Then you have $|g(x)-g(b)|<\varepsilon/2$ and $|g(b)-g(y)|<\varepsilon/2,$ so by the triangle inequality, $|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon.$

All that stuff about sequences is not needed here.

Comment: Had thought of this proof and wrote it, but thought of getting feedback on the above approach. Thanks so much, still.